# Assigning values to cross selection of MultiIndex DataFrame (ellipsis style of numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

In `numpy` we can select the last axis with ellipsis indexing, f.i. `array[..., 4]`.

In `Pandas` DataFrames for structuring large amounts of data, I like to use `MultiIndex` (which I see as some kind of additional dimensions of the DataFrame). If I want to select a given subset of a DataFrame `df`, in this case all columns `'key'` in the last level of the columns `MultiIndex`, I can do it with the cross selection method `xs`:

```
# create sample multiindex dataframe
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2), ('some', 'key', 'foo')))
data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(20, 18), columns=mi)

# make cross selection:
xs_df = data.xs('key', axis=1, level=-1)
```

But if I want to assign values to the cross selection, `xs` won't work.
The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) proposes to use `IndexSlice` to access and **set** values to a cross selection:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data.loc[:, idx[:, :, 'key']] *= 10
```

Which is working well as long as I **explicitly enter the number of levels** by inserting the correct amount of `:` before `'key'`.

Assuming I just want to give the number of levels to a selection function or f.i. always select the last level, **independent of the number of levels of the DataFrame**, this won't work (afaik).

My current workaround is using `None` slices for `n_levels` to skip:

```
n_levels = data.columns.nlevels - 1  # assuming I want to select the last level
data.loc[:, (*n_levels*[slice(None)], 'key')] *= 100
```

This is imho a quite nasty and cumbersome workaround. Is there any more pythonic/nicer/better way?

Comment: I'd really like to know why someone downvotes this question? It is clearly formulated, has a MWE and even a solution which I aim to improve. Please tell me what is wrong with the question instead of just silently downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you may be better off with `get_level_values`:

```
s = data.columns.get_level_values(-1) == 'key'
data.loc[:,s] *= 10
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than my workaround! I am still hoping for a more straightforward solution, thus I'll wait a few hours before accepting your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like we can do `update` and pass `drop_level` with `xs`

```
data.update(data.xs('key',level=-1,axis=1,drop_level=False)*10)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also a really nice solution. Only drawback is, that it creates a copy of the dataframe, resulting in a much lower performance than the other two methods (ca. a factor of 2 for small dataframes).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is as straightforward a way to index and set values the way you want. Adding to previous answers, I'd suggest naming your columns, ... makes it easier to wrangle with the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
#assign names
data.columns = data.columns.set_names(['first','second','third'])

#select interested level :
ind=data.T.query('third=="key"').index

#assign value
data.loc(axis=1)[ind] *=10
```